# Google Geocoding API V3 with api-key

Tags: google-geocoder

I want to upgrade our use of the google geocoding api from v2 using [geocoding.net](https://github.com/chadly/Geocoding.net) to v3, calling it from C# in a method similar to as is described [here](http://blog-of-darius.blogspot.com.au/2011/07/geocoding-with-c-and-google-geocoding_28.html)

Our clients currently use an non-business API key, as they don't need in excess of 25000 geocodes, though they may need to exceed the anonymous 2500 per day limit at times.

According to my google api console at https://code.google.com/apis/console, both my V2 and V3 keys have a limit of 25000 daily requests, however, although the Google Geocoding V3 API appears well documented, I can find no way to pass an API key to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [article](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2010/03/10/google-says-goodbye-to-api-keys-with-new-geocoding-api/), version 3 has no API keys.

Comment: this article is prior to june-2016.according to google geocode We no longer support keyless access (any request that doesn't include an API key). Future product updates are only available for requests made with an API key.All existing active domains and applications created before June 22, 2016, have been grandfathered. See below for specific details.